# How to write Unix EOL in R from Windows

Tags: r

I have several scripts that I need to update replacing a static value with another one. Currently I'm working on R for windows, and while get the output that I need, I can't get rid of the **^M** character on the output.

This is the code I have:

```
setwd("/home/scripts/")
filesInFolder <- list.files(path=".", pattern="\\.k$", recursive=TRUE)
for( currentFile in filesInFolder ){
    fileContent <- readLines(currentFile)
    varToReplace <- "WORKDIR"
    varReplacement <- "$MY_VAR"
    strToSearch <- paste("(.*\\/)(", varToReplace, ")(\\/.*)", sep="")
    #"(.*\\/)(WORKDIR)(\\/.*)"
    strReplacement <- paste( "\\1", varReplacement, "\\3", sep="")
    #"\\1$MY_VAR\\3"
    newFileContent <- gsub(strToSearch, strReplacement, fileContent )
    print(newFileContent)
    currentFile <- paste(currentFile, "b", sep="")
    cat(newFileContent, file=currentFile, sep="\n")
}
```

This is one of the files I'm reading:

```
#!/bin/ksh

CURRENT_DIRECTORY=/WORKDIR/something

ls $CURRENT_DIRECTORY
#some logic
#more logic
```

And this is the output file I get:

```
#!/bin/ksh^M
^M
CURRENT_DIRECTORY=/$MY_VAR/something^M
^M
ls $CURRENT_DIRECTORY^M
#some logic^M
#more logic^M
```

Since I have to replace around 200+ instances of this value, I would like to make it automatized. I know there is something called *dos2unix*, but as I said, I'm working on windows and since these files are going to be uploaded into a repository and downloaded from there, I would need to upload them, download them in a Linux box and re-upload them. I can't use R in Linux either.

Thanks.

**Edit**
The source files already have Unix format -I can see it on Notepad++-, the problem is with the output.

Comment: Look at `?Quotes` where the answer to the question "what is the EOL character?" is found to be `"\n"` and you are also told how to denote any character in a manner that the R interpreter will accept.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (and I am on Windows). The output file I get is merged all on one line, which is what you would expect when you set `sep=""` in your final `cat`.

Comment: @nograpes Hi, sorry I was trying with \n and \r but \n gives me the ^M, and R writes everything on one single line.

Comment: I agree that something odd is going on here. I suggest you shorten your question to this: `fileContent <- readLines(textConnection('first\r\nsecond\r\n'));cat(fileContent,file='test.kb', sep='\n')`. For some reason, the `\r` are still included despite how you specify the output.

Comment: @nograpes If I do that, I get this: first^M
second^M
^M

Comment: The point wasn't a fix to your problem, but simply a way of shortening your question to focus on the problem.

Comment: In the documentation for `writeLines` there is a clue that somewhere in the C code, `\n` is being converted to `\r\n` on Windows: `Normally writeLines is used with a text-mode connection, and the default separator is converted to the normal separator for that platform (LF on Unix/Linux, CRLF on Windows). For more control, open a binary connection and specify the precise value you want written to the file in sep. For even more control, use writeChar on a binary connection.
`

Comment: You can use dos2unix on Windows. There is no need to go to Linux. http://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do what I want, but I am not quite sure it is the optimal solution.

```
setwd("/home/scripts/")
filesInFolder <- list.files(path=".", pattern="\\.k$", recursive=TRUE)
for( currentFile in filesInFolder ){
    fileContent <- readLines(currentFile)
    varToReplace <- "WORKDIR"
    varReplacement <- "$MY_VAR"
    strToSearch <- paste("(.*\\/)(", varToReplace, ")(\\/.*)", sep="")
    #"(.*\\/)(WORKDIR)(\\/.*)"
    strReplacement <- paste( "\\1", varReplacement, "\\3", sep="")
    #"\\1$MY_VAR\\3"
    newFileContent <- gsub(strToSearch, strReplacement, fileContent )
    charVector <- strsplit(newFileContent,"")
    rawFileContent <- NULL
    for(currentString in charVector)
    {
        currentString <- unlist(lapply(currentString, charToRaw))
        #convert every char to raw
        rawFileContent <- c(rawFileContent, currentString, charToRaw("\n"))
        #concatenate raw string with \n, to differentiate strings
    }   
    currentFile <- paste(currentFile, "b", sep="")
    fileConn <- file(currentFile, "wb")
    writeBin(rawFileContent, fileConn)  
    close(fileConn)
}
```